# Filter a list based on values compared against a string

Tags: python

First off, this is my first question on here so if I do something wrong please let me know.

Ok, now to the problem. I am trying to search a list of words and remove any word that doesn't contain a set letter or letters in no particular order. I have tried using the in function as shown below. The list_to_clean shown here is the first few words of the list as an example, the list is really 15,000 values long.

```
list_to_clean = ['aalii', 'aargh', 'aaron', 'abaci', 'abada', 'abaft', 'abama', 'aband', 'abash', 'abate', 'abave', 'abbas', 'abbes', 'abbot', 'abdat', 'abeam', 'abear', 'abele', 'aberr', 'abhor', 'abidi', 'abyes', 'abime', 'abyss', 'abkar', 'abler', 'ablet', 'abm', 'aboma', 'abord', 'abort', 'about', 'abray', 'abram', 'abret', 'abrim']
cleanby = "ar"

def list_cleaner(cleanby:str, list_to_clean:list):
dict = list_to_clean
for letter in cleanby:
    for word in dict:
        if letter in word:
            nothing = 1
        else:
            dict.remove(word)
return(dict)
```

I have also tried using re.

```
def list_cleaner(cleanby:str, list_to_clean:list):
dict = list_to_clean
for letter in cleanby:
    for word in dict:
        if search(letter, word):
            nothing = 1
        else:
            dict.remove(word)
return(dict)
```

I don't know what the problem is but it works great for about the first 1000 or so words. Then, after a little while, it stops working and lets words thought that don't contain my "key" letters.
I am sure there is a really simple reason for this but I am new to python and programming so really basic things stump me.

Thanks in advance for all of yalls help.

Comment: Why have you not indented the contents of your function?

Comment: You should not modify a list you are iterating over. This does **not** make a copy: `dict = list_to_clean` (and you shouldn't use `dict` as a variable name). You are still modifying `list_to_clean`.

Comment: You are modifying the list as you iterate over it. Don't do that. It is also very, very inefficient

Comment: @Mark especially if that variable is **not** a dict

Comment: Look into "Pass by Object Reference", "Shallow Copy", and "Deep Copy", they may be confusing for a newbie but its an essential for coding in python. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-by-reference-vs-value-in-python/ https://medium.com/@thawsitt/assignment-vs-shallow-copy-vs-deep-copy-in-python-f70c2f0ebd86 These touch on what @Mark is talking about.

Comment: an easy way to make a propery copy is with .copy() ex new_list = old_list.copy()

Comment: @HershJoshi Thanks for the resources I will give them a read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that I was modifying a list that I was iterating through. Someone kindly brought this to my attention in the comments. Don't know how I missed it tbh.

In case you are wondering this is the full def now that it is working.

```
def list_cleaner(cleanby:str, list_to_clean:list):
"""Returns a filtered list of strings that contains all of the letters in the cleanby string.

Args:
    cleanby (str): Letters you want contained in the returned strings
    list_to_clean (list): List that you want cleaned.
"""
dict = list_to_clean.copy()
for letter in cleanby:
    for word in list_to_clean:
        if letter in word:
            nothing = 1
        else:
            try:
                dict.remove(word)
            except:
                nothing = 1
return(dict)
```

ps. I know it is generally not smart to use dict as a variable name but makes sense in the larger scheme of things. Also, the missing indent in the def has something to do with the copy and paste, in the program it is properly indented.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using sets for this. If you want to know if the letters `"ar"` exist in the word `"alright"` you can use:

```
set("ar").issubset("alright")
#True

set("ar").issubset("any")
#False
```

Together you can make a simple list comprehension:

```
list_to_clean = ['aalii', 'aargh', 'aaron', 'abaci', 'abada']
cleanby = "ar"

[word for word in list_to_clean if not set(cleanby).issubset(word)]
# ['aalii', 'abaci', 'abada']
```

You can make it a tiny bit more efficient by making the set outside:

```
letter_set = set(cleanby)

[word for word in list_to_clean if not letter_set.issubset(word)]
```

So you should be able to simply return the list if you still want the function:

```
list_to_clean = ['aalii', 'aargh', 'aaron', 'abaci', 'abada', 'cright', 'riant', 'ra']
cleanby = "ar"

def list_cleaner(cleanby:str, list_to_clean:list):
    letter_set = set(cleanby)
    return [word for word in list_to_clean if not letter_set.issubset(word)]

list_cleaner(cleanby, list_to_clean)
# ['aalii', 'abaci', 'abada', 'cright']
```

Comment: I tried implamenting the more efficient code you gave me but that seems to work even worse. Before it would filter the 15000 words down to about 7000. After implementing what you gave me it filters it down to 13000. And after a quick skim though the print out it I can't figure out what words it is sorting out but it def ins't words that don't contain "ar". Any ideas why this is? Also, thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have an example of a word that contains `ar` that this doesn't filter? Also, make sure you are not just adding this inside your loops. This replaces the loops and deletes by making a new list.

Comment: @Sven see the edit just to double check.

Comment: Ya, I replaced the loops inside my def and set your list comprehension (I think that's what it is called) equal to a variable and then returned the variable and printed it to check if it is working. Here are a few of the words that aren't right from one section. 'feedy', 'feeds', 'feely', 'feels'.

Comment: I'm confused @Sven those words don't have an `a` or `r`. Shouldn't they be in the returned list?

Comment: No, the list is only supposed to return words that don't have 'a' or 'r'. But now that you mention it, your function words perfectly for liftering out all words that have both an 'a' and a 'r'

Comment: If you want to remove words that have an `a` or an `r` or both you can look at the intersection.  `not letter_set.intersection(word)`. If that's what you are after, I'll change the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off thinking about this as generating a new list containing the words you want to keep, rather than removing words from the initial list.

That can be done with a straightforward list comprehension.

```
[w for w in list_to_clean if not all(ltr in w for ltr in set(cleanby))]
```